# How can I print Scala variables (in scala objects) on console, If I have to run the app via bash script?

Tags: bash, scala

I have a Scala application which I start with a bash script. In this bash script I call the env-script, property-files and run a Service Action script.

In my Scala files I have several printlns, which I would like to see on the console.

Does anyone know how I can show these printlns through the console when I run the bash script?

Kind regards
nika

Comment: How do you run the bash script and how does it run the Scala application? Normally, `println` prints to STDOUT, and normally STDOUT shows up in the console directly when you run something. Maybe you are piping that output somewhere else (such in a log file)? But that would be controlled by your script (or the Service Action whatever that is).

Comment: Per the above comment, something in your code is "eating" your STDOUT `println`s.  Without seeing your code there is really no way to help. You need to edit your Q to include the smallest amount of code that readers can copy//paste into their scala environment that demonstrates this problem.